# Pagina no PHP conecta no banco, carrega mas não apaga

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Vocês poderiam me ajudar a identificar o que há de errado com esse código?

```
<?php
     include ("conexao.php");?>
     <?php
     $id = isset ($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id']:'';
     $sql= "DELETE FROM `guaxinim` WHERE `guaxinim`.`id`=".$id;
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if($result)
         die ("O registro foi excluído.");
      else
         echo "Infelizmente não foi possível excluir.";

    header('Location: cadastros.php');
?>
```

pois a pagina carrega quando tiro o "header" aparece que deu certo e não aparenta erro, mas quando vou verificar o banco os dados ainda estão la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está trabalhando com `anchor` (*links* com parâmetros) e não com formulário (`<form>`), você deve utilizar `$_GET` ao invés de `$_POST`, por exemplo:

```
$id = isset ($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
```

Não esqueça de remover o `echo`, caso contrário `header` não irá funcionar.

Comment: Cara sensacional valeu mesmo pela velocidade de resposta e era exatamente isso que estava acontecendo deu tudo certo agora vlw irmão!!!